# Javascript switch statement fails on split string

Tags: javascript, split, switch-statement

I am currently writing a class project that interprets one language and outputs a result.

I read in a file and split the document by new lines to get an array of strings (aka each line)

Each line is is then further subdivded into and operator and sometimes a parameter. The issue I have lies with operators that do not have parameters.

an example of the language looks like this:

```
lvalue x //this declares a variable x
rvalue 5 //places the value 5 on the stack
:= //assign the value 5 to the variable x
```

I use a switch statement to read the operator and determine which function to call

```
call(){
switch(opp)
 {
 case "lvalue":lvalue(param); break;
 case "rvalue":rvalue(param); break;
 case ":=": set(); break;
 }
}
```

The major problem I am having is that an input of ":=" is being completely skipped over by the switch statement.

the input for opp and param and created by breaking up each line based on a space. Since := has no other values in the line, the result of the split is just the one item. I suspect that is where my issue is coming from.

I call to my switch statement like this:

```
var args=doc[i].split(' ');
var opp=args[0];
var param=args.splice(1,args.length).join(" ");

call(opp,param);
```

I noticed that when I places spaces after the := in the input file, the switch statement reads it. So I am certain this is an issue of parsing the strings correctly. This issue also occurs for other operators with no parameters (again with the spaces fixing the problem).

Since I can't guarantee spaces in the input, I need a way to ensure that my switch statement will recognize my operators.

Thanks

Comment: Can you display what array do you get or how does the file look? It seems that `trim` or `split` with different matcher might help.

Comment: if I do a split on my line with the ":=" I get an array of [":="]. There doesn't appear to be any spaces or malformations in the string.

Comment: But looking at a hex editor prior to adding any spaces, the ":=" only had newlines directly after them.

Comment: Can you share your `var args` array? Or a sample doc that is not working.

Comment: I simplified it a little bit, but you can run http://codepen.io/Ojiro/pen/ZezNPB?editors=0110 save the contents in the css section to a file and read it in.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It should solve your issue of whitespace around characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a problem with your arguments array, because the below example shows that switch works fine on a string `":="`:

http://codepen.io/DeividasK/pen/xqKNWr

Your issue can be solved by mapping the array and removing any whitespace. This can be done using `array = array.map(item => { return item.trim() })`. Important: `array.map` does not modify the original array, but returns a new array with modified values.

Comment: Yes, this helps. I'm guessing there was some non-visible stuff showing up in the operand.